# Javascript - Loop through select options clicking each one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to go through a select list with 200+ entries and click on each one. When an element is clicked on it executes a function selectCountry() which adds a line to a table. I want to have it create a table with every option selected. The page of interest is at: http://www.world-statistics.org/result.php?code=ST.INT.ARVL?name=International%20tourism,%20number%20of%20arrivals.

So far I have the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('selcountry');
var opts = sel.options;    
for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {selectCountry(opt.value)}
```

I am trying to do this in the console in Chrome.

Comment: I really hope this is for test code or something like that and you're not building a product/tool on this...

Comment: Please clarify just what it is that doesn't work. A jsfiddle would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most useful features of dev tools is that when you write the name of a function, you get back its source code. Here's the source code for the `selectCountry` function:

```
function selectCountry(select) { 
        if (select.value == "000") return;
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex]; 
        var ul = select.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]; 
        var choices = ul.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) 
            if (choices[i].value == option.value) {
                $("#selcountry:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                $('#selcountry').val('[]');
                return;
            } 
        var li = document.createElement('li'); 
        var input = document.createElement('input'); 
        var text = document.createTextNode(option.firstChild.data); 
        input.type = 'hidden'; 
        input.name = 'countries[]'; 
        input.value = option.value;
        li.appendChild(input); 
        li.appendChild(text); 
        li.onclick = delCountry;
        ul.appendChild(li);
        addCountry(option.firstChild.data, option.value);   
        $("#selcountry:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $('#selcountry').val('');
    }
```

Your flaw is now obvious. `selectCountry` accepts the entire ***select element*** as an argument as opposed to the ***select's value*** (which is a terrible design but meh). Instead of passing the value of the element, change its index:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('selcountry');
var opts = sel.options;    
for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    sel.selectedIndex = i
    selectCountry(sel)
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the explanation as well, a good lesson.